# Non-trivial example of a local optimum without satisfying Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) optimality conditions

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, non-convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am looking for an example of a locally optimal point of the nonlinear program:
$$\{ \min f(x) , g_i(x) \geq 0 \}$$
that does not have a singleton feasibility set.

e.g. **not** the example of $\{ \min x,  x^2\leq 0 \} $ found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513300/is-kkt-conditions-necessary-and-sufficient-for-any-convex-problems/2513724#2513724) where the feasibility set is just $\{0\}$.

Comment: Example 4.5.3 and Solution 4.5.4 of https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~drust/opt2017-part4.pdf provides such an example as per my comment at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4418465/what-is-the-meaning-of-local-optimality-in-nlp-mentioned-in-constraint-qualifi/4418601?noredirect=1#comment9246143_4418601